# Error when Running SvcUtil.exe Against Service WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a service proxy for a SOAP service exposed by another entity. After running:

```
svcutil.exe https://<domain-omitted>/feed30/clientdataservice.asmx?wsdl
```

I get the following error:

```
Attempting to download metadata from 'https://<domain-
omitted>/feed30/clientdataservice.asmx' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO
Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contain any valid contracts or services or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option.
```

I've seen in the past that this might be related to the utilities inability to access all of the xmlns paths in the WSDL. Those are:

```
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
xmlns:s2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
```

The only one included in an import statement in the WSDL is xmlns:s2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"

I can't find information that I once saw wherein you could manually download each schema document and provide it as a parameter to the svcutil utility. Am I on the right track, or should I be looking somewhere else?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: if you can get the wsdl itself through a webbrowser, save as file and run svcutil.exe against that. Any imports? save them aswell and adjust the wsdl to point to the local files.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The one questionable import is: xmlns:s2="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/". If you navigate to that URL, there's nothing there. Is there a workaround for a situation such as this?

Comment: The namespace URI's used in a WSDL document do NOT represent URL's. Just like any other language, they are 'unique' strings put onto the document container to prevent collision of the types defined within with other documents that want to specify the same types, but from a different namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per MarvinSmit's comment, I manually downloaded the WSDL data into a local file. I found a reference to the 'http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/' through Bing here, 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj675594(v=office.12).aspx'. I downloaded that into it's own .xsd file. I then replaced the import reference in the local WSDL to be that of the local XSD file. Ran svcutil pointed at my local WSDL file and *poof*, it generated a proxy that worked.