# Adding service reference generates empty reference.cs and empty config.svcinfo files

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

Im trying to connect to this web service: http://www.eotd.org/search/server/terminology-service-soap.wsdl

web service website: http://www.eccma.org/resources/webservices.php

When I add a service reference in C#, the generated reference.cs file is empty and the config.svcinfo and config91.svcinfo have nothing in their behaviours, bindings, and endpoints.
Also, not sure why but there are two different wsdl files in the service reference created.

I've tried the solutions posted on SO like unchecking "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" and changing the collection type to Generic.List but nothing worked so far.

Can anyone actually connect to this web service? Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran svcutil with the command `svcutil http://www.eotd.org/search/server/terminology-service-soap.wsdl` and got the following errors:

> C:\temp>svcutil
>   http://www.eotd.org/search/server/terminology-service-soap.wsdl
>   Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.33440] Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Attempting to download metadata from
>   'http://www.eotd.org/search/server/terminology-service-soap.wsdl'
>   using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO. Error: Cannot import
>   wsdl:portType Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL
>   import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Schema with target namespace
>   'urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:xml-schema:resolution-service-data'
>   could not be found. XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:web-service:terminology-service']/wsdl:portType[@na
>   me='terminology_service']
>
> Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: There was an error importing
>   a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on. XPath to
>   wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:web-service:terminology-service']/wsdl:portType[@n
>   ame='terminology_service'] XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:web-service:terminology-service:soap']/wsdl:binding
>   [@name='terminology_service_SOAP_binding']
>
> Error: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail: There was an error importing a
>   wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on. XPath to
>   wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:web-service:terminology-service:soap']/wsdl:binding
>   [@name='terminology_service_SOAP_binding'] XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:web-service:terminology-service:soap']/wsdl:service
>   [@name='terminology_service']/wsdl:port[@name='terminology_service_port']
>
> Generating files... Warning: No code was generated. If you were trying
>   to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did
>   not contain any valid contracts or services or because all
>   contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies.
>   Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.
>
> Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas
>   make sure to use the /dataContractOnly option.

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL you have linked to is valid. However, it looks like the microsoft tooling cannot follow relative import paths - John Saunders tried svcutil.exe and I just had a go using wsdl.exe.

And unfortunatelt the WSDL exposed here is full of them.

For example,

```
<wsdl:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:web-service:terminology-service" location="terminology-service.wsdl"/>
```

links to the following location: http://www.eotd.org/search/server/terminology-service.wsdl

And from this file there are more imports:

```
<xsd:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-5:ed-1:tech:xml-schema:identifier" schemaLocation="identifier.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:xml-schema:resolution-service-data" schemaLocation="resolution-service-data.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:xml-schema:terminology-service-data" schemaLocation="terminology-service-data.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-6:ed-1:tech:xml-schema:terminology-service-dictionary" schemaLocation="terminology-service-dictionary.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:ts:29002:-20:ed-1:tech:xml-schema:ontology-service-data" schemaLocation="ontology-service-data.xsd"/>
```

all of which are relative import paths too. I have looked at a couple of these XSD imports and they also include relative import paths.

So the easiest thing to do is find a way of making your tooling follow relative paths. You could also manually download each resource file and then edit them to make sure all import paths are absolute. However, I'm not sure if the microsoft tooling can follow paths on the filesystem or if they need to be URIs.

If not, then you have to tell the vendor that you cannot consume the service because you need absolute URIs for all the various imports.

**EDIT**
Someone else appears to have had success with local import paths here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19912058/569662